# How to count the words of a string without using any function in abap

Tags: abap

**Hello Experts**

*I need a help to count the words of string without using any function in ABAP.
We can only use `do` loop and `if` condition.*

**Please Help**

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: are you his teacher? :D

Comment: It sounds like homeworking! [Here is how you should ask the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Asking someone to provide code for a homework question.  Has not shown any effort to attempt  the problem themself.

Answer (score 2):

```
METHODS count_words
  IMPORTING
    iv_text          TYPE string
  RETURNING
    VALUE(rv_result) TYPE i.

METHOD count_words.
  CONSTANTS lc_space TYPE string VALUE ` `.
  DATA(lv_remaining_text) = iv_text.
  DATA(lv_last_char) = ``.
  DO.
    IF lv_remaining_text IS INITIAL.
      RETURN. " or EXIT if you omit the METHOD around this
    ENDIF.
    DATA(lv_next_char) = lv_remaining_text(1).
    IF lv_next_char <> lc_space AND
       ( lv_last_char IS INITIAL OR
         lv_last_char = lc_space ).
      rv_result = rv_result + 1.
    ENDIF.
    lv_last_char = lv_next_char.
    lv_remaining_text = lv_remaining_text+1.
  ENDDO.
ENDMETHOD.
```

**Please don't code like this in practice.** This sort of low-level character juggling is only for educational purposes.

In real life, please use something like this:

```
METHOD count_words_cleanly.
  rv_result = count( val   = iv_text
                     regex = `(\s\S|^\S)` ).
ENDMETHOD.
```

Comment: teacher said you are not allowed to use constants :p we should rather find this guy teaching abap this way...

Comment: LOL. Okay, but I coded this blindfolded and with one hand bound to my back, while hopping on one foot, so at least I lived up to his/her other side conditions. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of spaces between your words.
You need at least STRLEN to determine the string length... without it I dont think this works. CONDENSE might be useful in some cases... give it a try without CONDENSE.

```
DATA a TYPE string VALUE 'MY NAME IS JOHN'.
DATA c TYPE i.
DATA d TYPE c.
DATA words TYPE i value 1.
DATA e TYPE i VALUE 0.

CONDENSE a.
c = STRLEN( a ).
DO c TIMES.
  d = a+e(1).
  e = e + 1.
  IF d = ' '.
    words = words + 1.
  ENDIF.
ENDDO.
WRITE words. // just as output ... delete on demand
```